# iPhone 6 screen is on while on a call

Tags: iphone

I expect my screen to go inactive when I hold my iPhone 6 up to my face. This is not happening, and I'm hitting mute with my cheek.

The proximity sensor appears to be working, at least according to the three "phone test" apps I tried, all of which said it triggered when I moved my hand toward it.

Assuming the hardware is working, what else might cause this? I am running the recent version of iOS 11, and do not have a screen protector.

Comment: I put it back in my pocket *after* making a call, which is why it pocket dials.

Comment: Why is it still on when I am on a call then?

Comment: As I stated in the original post, the display is active while I am on a call and it is held up to my face.

Comment: Hows that? Now do you have an actual suggestion?